# jquery functions overloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a function binded to a .click() event. Each time the user clicks, the browser fadeOut() the current element and animate() the marginLeft of the new element. For some reason when I click fast on the button which is binded to this click event, in Chrome it jumpes the animation and just go on directly to the next on (only if I click like 5 times in 1 second) and don't add the marginLeft, in this case it causes a major usability issue for the UI. Is there any fallback for this scenario? Like if the animation is not completed directly add it with css() or something like that?

Thanks

E: The click() event calls a function where all the magic happens, if it helps ..

Comment: Probably you should provide jsFiddle demo, it is hard to deduce anything from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into jquery's `.stop()` method. It allows you to short-circuit any currently-running animations on an element.

Simple example:

```
$myElement.on('click', function() {
    // first 'true' clears animations in the queue for this element
    // second 'true' completes the currently-running animation immediately
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/